# Next and previous record - the most optimal way - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

In all my controllers in the `show` method I create two variables to get a next and previous record in my view files:

```
// get previous user id
$previous = Question::where('id', '<', $object->id)->max('id');
// get next user id
$next = Question::where('id', '>', $object->id)->min('id');
```

### My question

Is there a more optimal way to get the values?
Maybe in model file?

Thx

Comment: I think no from model, because you are passing parameter to get records i.e. $object. There might be some way but I have been doing laravel for long period of time and there is no optimal way with model for this. In my view.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about moving the logic to the parent Controller, so that the code would be available to all child controllers. Is that reasonable and worth the effort?

Comment: can you explain reason behind show function in each controller

Comment: Well, the function is a standard part of any resource controller - just like here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers
Do you know of an alternative for it?

Comment: means you have multiple controllers with show function but, inside show function you have used different model or same model

Answer (score 0):

you can use `limit 1`. 
`$obj = Question::where('id', '>', $object->id)
          ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
          ->first();
$id = $obj->id;`

```
$obj = Question::where('id', '<', $object->id)
      ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
      ->first();
$id = $obj->id;
```